# Populate select with keys from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js, mongodb

I have an array with an object in it, this is returned to the client through node.js server running with mongodb. I want to select all keys/fields in object(i.e. name, surname, telephone) but not their values(i.e i just want "name" string and not "some name" value), and then to populate those keys in a select menu using jquery.

```
[
  {
    "name": "some name",
    "surname": "some surname",
    "telephone": "123456",
    "address": "street123",
    "_id": "52751d39b188f14026002711"
  }
]
```

Below is how i get documents in json format to the client and how i populate select menu(#parameter). Right now it is populating select with whole json document, meaning every key/value pairs.

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost:3000/findAll/"+ coll, function (result) {
     $.each(result, function(i){
        $('#parameter').append('<option>'+JSON.stringify(result[i])+'</option>')
     })                        
});
```

Second part of the question is how to select distinct/unique keys if i get multiple mongodb documents with different keys to the client. To be clear the role of the select menu is for user to be able to select by which key he wants to search the whole collection in mongodb. I'm not sure if i am clear here, but answering at least first part of the question would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jzmtL/1/):

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost:3000/findAll/"+ coll, function (result) {
  $.each(result, function(i, element){
    for (var prop in element){
        if (element.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
          $('#parameter').append('<option>'+ prop +'</option>')
        }
    }                     
});
```

The second part of the question is not too clear. Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: Wow, thanks for quick response, it worked like a charm, much appreciated. About the second part of the question. Let's say i get the above json to client, along with another object that has all keys like the first one. How do i populate select menu with unique keys only, and not with same keys twice or more. Because now if i have 2 objects with same keys it will insert and keys will repeat inside select menu. Sorry if this is a lame problem, i'm sort of a beginner.

Comment: Well, that depends on your UI. How will the user access each one of the two separate objects? Will you have another dropdown which lists the objects? This #parameter dropdown should be used for only one object at a time.